# loop that moves first character in string behind the 2nd two characters and repeats every 3 characters

Tags: string, loops, for-loop

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i * 3 < len; i++)
        if (len >= 3) {
            return str = str.substring((i * 3) + 1, (i * 3) + 3) + str.substring((i * 3), (i * 3) + 1);
        }

    return str;
}
```

I need the string to work in all situations, it works with strings three         characters and below. But it will not run the for loop, so it will not work with strings larger than 3 characters. Also anything under three characters stays the same and is unedited. This is what I have so far Ex: "to" - "to", "tca"-"cat", "tcagdo" - "cat", ""-"".

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then the answer should be :-

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i * 3 < len-2; i++)
        if (len >= 3) {
            result = result + str.substring((i * 3) + 1, (i * 3) + 3) + str.substring((i * 3), (i * 3) + 1);
        }

    return result;
}
```